# How to manually set the record seperator in awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file like below -

```
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore
    something something .......
;
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore
    something something .......(testing
)
;
vipin kumar ......................... kumar .....bangalore
something something ;
```

I want the output like below ( name and number can be different in the file but the only thing that is common - line is ending when we have ";")

```
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore   something something .......;
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore    something something .......(testing);
vipin kumar ......................... kumar .....bangaloresomething something ;

I want to set the RS to ";" .
```

I tried below commands -

```
awk '{ORS=(NR%2==0?RS:FS)}1' file.txt
```

but it is not giving the correct output because

`NR%2 or NR%3` won't work as i am not sure after how many lines i will get `;`

then i tried to set the RS to ; using below

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) (ORS=(if($i ~ /;/?RS:FS);break}1' file.txt
```

But this command is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat f
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore
    something something .......
;
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore
    something something .......(testing
)
;
vipin kumar ......................... kumar .....bangalore
something something ;
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'ORS=/;/?RS:FS'  f
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore     something something ....... ;
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore     something something .......(testing ) ;
vipin kumar ......................... kumar .....bangalore something something ;
```

Comment: Nice.. this is something that i was trying from last 1 hour.. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Akshay , I cam across a similar problem but cannot understand your solution here , Could you please explain what your command is doing ?

Comment: @Vicky if line/record/row contains semicolon `;` then set output row separator (`ORS`) to default row separator (`RS`) that is `\n` else set `ORS` to Field separator `FS` that is single space, above syntax is equal to `awk '{ if ( $0 ~ /;/) { ORS = RS } else { ORS = FS } ; print $0 }' file`  where `$0` is current record/row/line

Answer (score 2):

@VIPIN KUMAR: Try:

```
awk '/^vipin kumar/ && Q{print Q;Q=$0;next} {Q=Q?Q FS $0:$0} END{print Q}' Input_file
```

**EDIT:** As per OP's requirement following could help too.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",$0,$0~/\;/?RS:"")}'  Input_file
```

Comment: How to pass below test case - (different name in the begining of  lines )

arun kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore
    something something .......
;
varun kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore
    something something .......(testing
)
;
vipin kumar ......................... kumar .....bangalore
something something ;

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR:Which test case ? Could you please let me know.
EDIT: As per your shown Input_file code was given, if you have any other requirements then you have to tell us what is common or by which pattern you need to get the data?

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: Kindly EDIT your post and try to pos this new scenario into code tags as I am not able to understand it without code tags.

Comment: Agree with your comment - 
The only thing that is common : line should be completed when it find ";"

Comment: As suggested - Question has been updated with condition.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: Could you please try my edited answer now and let me know how it goes then?

Answer (score 1):

I got the Answer, but there may be other way to do that.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) (ORS=($i ~ /;/)?RS:FS)}1' file.txt
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore     something something ....... ;
vipin kumar ........................ kumar ......bangalore     something something .......(testing ) ;
vipin kumar ......................... kumar .....bangalore something something ;
```

Answer (score 1):

My first intention was to use this:

```
awk '{gsub(/\n/,"",$0); printf "%s;\n", $0}'  ORS='\n' RS=\; a.txt
```

... but I really like [Akshay Hegde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41957985/171318).

Comment: Unfortunately it will remove `;` at the end

Comment: @AkshayHegde I see. Changed.

Comment: `^1` now looks fine